# Probability conundrum

Tags: probability

Good morning,

wondered if you could help me please?

I would like to work out the probability of and event happening 5 times out of 6.

all 6 events have a 1 in 60 chance of a particular outcome. I would like to know what the probability is when the event happens 6 times, and 5 of which have the same outcome.

if you could help it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 1):

Your situation correspond to [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=6$ and $p=1/60$ where each of 6 trials can have 60 possible outcomes.

First, let us focus on the $i$th term of the binomial expansion that corresponds that one fixed outcome (say $1$) occurs
$$
{{n}\choose{i}}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
$$
Specifically:
$$
{{6}\choose{5}}\left(\frac{1}{60}\right)^5\frac{59}{60}
$$
Since each of the $n=6$ can have values $1,2,\dots 60$, we have to multiply this term by 60, i.e.
$$
{{6}\choose{5}}\left(\frac{1}{60}\right)^5 59
$$

Comment: This is not the probability of a 5-tie.

Comment: There are 60 outcomes, so you need to multiply by 60

Comment: so there is a 1 in (x?) chance of this happening?

Comment: sorry, the $X$ was somehow misleading, I have changed it a little.

Comment: can i have that in simple maths please?